# Gortz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry Theorem 13.84

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'am reading Gortz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry, p.403 Theorem 13.84

[image]

Here, the corresponding morphism $r$ in the statement means that the element of $Hom_S(X, \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}))$ corresponding from $\mathcal{H} := ker(f^{*}\mathcal{E}\to \mathcal{L})$ via the bijection in the page 381 of the book.

[image]

Anyway, I'm trying to understand the above underliend statement.

My strategy is as follows,

First, fix $s \in S$.  Consider next commutative diagram

$$
  \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
  \newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
  %
  \begin{array}{llllllllllll}
   X':=X \times_{S}k(s) \ \ &  \ \ra {i_s^{'}} \ & X & \ra{r} \ & P:= \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})   \\
   \da{f^{'}} & & \da{f} & & \swarrow{h} & &  \\
   \operatorname{Spec}k(s) & \ra{i_s} & S &   \\
  \end{array}
  $$
where $f^{'}$ is proper since the 'properness' is stable under base change.

Next, note that

1. $i_s^{'*}(\mathcal{L})$ is $f^{'}$ -ample ( by the proposition 13.64)
2. $i_s^{*}(\mathcal{E})$ is also quasi-coherent.
3. There is a surjective homomorphism $f^{'*}(i_s^{*}(\mathcal{E})) \to i_s^{'*}(\mathcal{L})$ (Since there is a surjective homomorphism $f^{*}\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{L}$ and $i_s^{'*}$ is right exact, $i_s^{'*}(f^{*}\mathcal{E}) \to i_s^{'*}\mathcal{L}$ is also surjective and note that  $i_s^{'*}(f^{*}\mathcal{E}) = f^{'*}(i_s^{*}\mathcal{E})$ by the above commutative diagram).

Now let $r_s : X^{'} \to \mathbb{P}(i_s^{*}(\mathcal{E})) = i_s^{*}(\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})) := \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}) \times_{S} k(s) $ be the corresponding morphism as in the Teorem 13.84( where the first equality is by his book p.215-(8.8.3) and the second equality is by the definition of the inverse image of scheme(his book p.105)). We have a commutative diagram ;

$$
  \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
  \newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
  %
  \begin{array}{llllllllllll}
   X' \ \ &  \ \ra {r_s} \ & \mathbb{P}(i_s^{*}\mathcal{E})=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})\times_{S} k(s) \\
   \da{f^{'}} & & \swarrow{h_s} &  \\
   \operatorname{Spec}k(s)   \\
  \end{array}
  $$

, where $i_s^{'*}(\mathcal{L})$ is $f^{'}$ -ample.

Since $s\in S$ is arbitrary, by the reduction assumption, we have that $r_s$ is finite for all $s \in S$. In particular, All $r_s$ is quasi-finite($\because$ Corollary 12.89) and has finite fibers.

Now, note that

1. $  X' := X \times_S k(s) \cong f^{-1}(s)$ and $\mathbb{P}(i_s^{*}\mathcal{E})=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})\times_{S} k(s) \cong h^{-1}(s)$ as topological spaces. So, we have $r_s : f^{-1}(s) \to h^{-1}(s)$ for all $s\in S$.

2-1) For all $s\in S$, $im(r|_{f^{-1}(s)}) \subseteq h^{-1}(s)$ ($\because f = h\circ r$)

**2-2) For all $s\in S$, $r|_{f^{-1}(s)} = r_s$  ?**

Assume that 2-2) is also true. Now let $p \in P:=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}) = \bigcup_{s\in S}h^{-1}(s)$. Then $p\in h^{-1}(s_0)$ for some $s_0 \in S$. Consider $r_{s_0} : f^{-1}(s_0) \to h^{-1}(s_0)$. If the above 2-1), 2-2) are true, then we can show that
$$r^{-1}(p) \subseteq r_{s_0}^{-1}(p)$$. So $r^{-1}(p)$ is finite set and we are done.

So in my strategy, key point is relation between $r$ and $r_s$ ; 2-2).

Is 2-2) true? Then how can we show that?

Can anyone help?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Im unsure how you define $\mathbb{P}(E)$. The usual definition and notation is $\mathbb{P}(E^*):=Proj(Sym_{\mathcal{O}_S}^*(E^*))$ - you must dualize $E$ to $E^*$.With this definition there is a 1-1 correspondence between (classes of) surjections $f^*(E^*) \rightarrow L \rightarrow 0, L\in Pic(S)$ and maps (over $S$) $\phi_L: X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(E^*)$. Note that you should use quotients when representing this functor and not sub-sheaves.

Comment: Uhm..$\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$ is the projective bundle defined as Grassmannian $\operatorname{Grass}^{1}(\mathcal{E})$ (His book p.215) Any other or further information you need?

Comment: I do not have a copy of this book, but it seems you are studying $Proj(Sym_{\mathcal{O}_S}(E))$. In this generality when you are studying $\mathbb{P}(E)$ where $E$ is a quasi coherent sheaf, you must worry about these issues. You are speaking about sub-sheaves $ker(f^*E \rightarrow L)$. Pulling back a surjection remains a surjection but pulling back an injection does not remain an injection. Hence you must use "quotients" when constructing the projective space bundle using representable functors.

Comment: Uhm..Do I understand your comment well? I used the fact that "pulling back a surjection remains a surjection by taking $i_s^{'*}$ on the surjection $f^{*}E \to L$ and get a surjection $f^{'*}(i_s^{*}(E)) \to i_s^{'*}(L)$. $i_s^{'*}(L)$ is also invertible module(line bundle). Then take a kernel $\mathcal{H}_s := ker(f^{'*}(i_s^{*}(E)) \to i_s^{'*}(L))$ and we get a corresponding morphism $r_s : X' \to \mathbb{P}(i_s^{*}(E))$ by the bijection in the above image.

Comment: But I don't know the explicit inverse map of the bijection. 
     Specific presentation of the inverse map is maybe key point for understanding relation between $r$ and $r_s$ in my strategy.

Comment: And.. what "you must use 'quotients'" means? What relation may exists between your comment and our goal?

Comment: Again I do not have a copy of the book. If you try to define the "functor" $F(X \to S):=\{L \subseteq f^*E:L\in Pic(X)\}/\cong$ then this is not a well defined functor: Pulling back an injection is no longer an injection.

Comment: O.K. I'll try to think about your comment. Thanks :)

Comment: Projective space $\mathbb{P}(V^*)$ of a vector space $V$ is a parameter space "parametrizing lines in $V$" or dually "line quotients $V^* \rightarrow l$ of the dual $V^*$". If you want to formulate this as a functor and to represent this functor, you must use "linebundle quotients". Else you do not get a well defined functor to represent.